# Do I need to soak fresh beans?

Tags: beans

I have scarlet runner beans in my garden this year. I just picked my first batch of dry pods and shelled them. Most of the recipes I find online assume that you are buying or using dry beans and call for a 4-6 hour pre-soak.

I have cooked dried black beans and pinto beans before using a pre-soak, and the beans are usually hard and wrinkled before soaking and smooth and plump afterwards. My scarlet runner beans are already plump and smooth straight out of the pod.

Do I need to soak them before cooking? What about other bean varieties? If I grew black or pinto beans in the garden, would I need to soak them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you don't need to soak fresh shell beans.

> Unlike their dried counterparts, shelling beans don't need a soak before using. Most fresh shelling beans require from 20 to 30 minutes to cook

[The Spruce Eats](https://www.thespruceeats.com/all-about-shelling-beans-2217277)

I'm not sure where they got the idea that most fresh shell beans take 20-30 minutes.  You'll find recipes that vary from 10 to 60 minutes of cooking time.

Here's a recipe from the New York Times (maybe behind a paywall - sorry) that has you cook beans for 55 minutes: [Shell Bean Ragout](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1017688-shell-bean-ragout).  And you may appreciate that this recipe specifically mentions scarlet runner beans as one of the varieties that would work here.

> Shell beans take less than half the time to cook than their dried counterparts. Look for varieties such as mottled pink and white cranberry beans, also known as borlotti beans; large scarlet runner beans that are mottled and purple, despite the name; and pale yellow cannellini beans.

I have never seen fresh black or pinto beans being sold, but my guess is this has to do with economics, rather than edibility.

Comment: Lots of beans are toxic until they're cooked properly, which is why they're cooked at the factory and rarely sold uncooked. Scarlet runner beans are _minimally_ toxic [according to random google results, YMMV] but definitely cook them properly to avoid digestive unpleasantness.